# Element API: Remove additional set of square brackets from JSON-String

Tags: plugin-elementapi, json, format

We're currently having an Android-App access some of the entries of our Craft-based website. We are currently still using a self built API, and for easier creation of new API-Calls we are trying to migrate over to Pixel & Tonic's Element API plugin.

The entries (or the blocks of a Matrix-field of that entry, to be more precise) are accessed like so:

```
'api/alloverlist' => function() { // GET ALLOVER-CHALLENGES
        return [
            'elementType' => ElementType::Entry,
            'criteria' => [
                'section' => 'challenges',
                ],
            'paginate' => false,
            'first' => true,
            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry){

                $allOverChallenges = [];
                foreach ($entry->allOverChallenge as $challenge){
                    $allOverChallenges[] = [
                        'elementId' => $challenge->id,
                        'field_allOverChallenge_allOverName' => $challenge->allOverName,
                    ];
                }

                return [
                    $allOverChallenges
                ];
            },
        ];
    },
```

The returned JSON-String has the following appearance:

```
[
[
    {
        "elementId": "1298",
        "field_allOverChallenge_allOverName": "Dein schönster Sonnenaufgang"
    },
    {
        "elementId": "1310",
        "field_allOverChallenge_allOverName": "AllOverChallenge2"
    },
    {
        "elementId": "1318",
        "field_allOverChallenge_allOverName": "Allover Challenge 3"
    }
]
]
```

However, the Android-App accepts the JSON-String just with single square-brackets, like so:

```
[
   {
     "key":"value",
      ...
   },

   {
     "key":"value",
      ...
   }
]
```

For the sake of not having to change the existing Android-App, is it somehow possible to remove the additional square brackets?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I don't know the Element API, have you tried

```
    return $allOverChallenges;
```

instead of

```
    return [
        $allOverChallenges
    ];
```

It looks like you are simply adding these brackets (Array) on the return.

Comment: Well, that sure was easy and obvious, wasn't it? It works, thank you! I feel really dumb now :)