# Return JSON array without extra square brackets

Tags: plugin-elementapi, craft2

I'm having difficulties to remove an additional set of square brackets or avoid including them within array.

My JavaScript code currently accesses array's object at 0 index and therefore I'd have to loop in one level deeper array. Which I'd like to avoid if possible.

**This is my endpoint:**

```
'pricelist/<entryId:\d+>.json' => function($entryId) {
    return [
        'elementType' => ElementType::Entry,
        'criteria' => [
            'section' => "products",
            'descendantOf' => $entryId,
        ],
        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {

            $products = [];
            // "orderItem" is entry field
            foreach ( $entry->orderItem as $product ) {
                $products[] = [
                    'title' => $product->titleVariation,
                ];
            }
            return $products;
        },
    ];
},
```

**Returned JSON array is:**

```
{"data":
    [
        [
            {
                "title": "a",
            },
            {
                "title": "b",
            },
            {
                "title": "c",
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

**Expected JSON array output:**

```
{"data":
    [
        {
            "title": "a",
        },
        {
            "title": "b",
        },
        {
            "title": "c",
        }
    ]
}
```

I have almost the same scenario from [**this question**](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21572/element-api-remove-additional-set-of-square-brackets-from-json-string/21574#21574) but the answer wasn't my issue.

Comment: Did you checked `'title' => $product->titleVariation` while adding to array.I mean is there any need to wrap `title in  [ ]`

Comment: @inrsaurabh not wrapping it gives a syntax error because the key must be within `[]`. And furthermore not assigning key name gives the same output - two dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

change `$products[] =` to `$products =` in your for each loop, that should fix the extra square brackets. And if you want to get all entries and their titleVariation fields you should use `'elementType' => Entry::Class`

```
'pricelist/<entryId:\d+>.json' => function($entryId) {
    return [
        'elementType' => Entry::Class,
        'criteria' => [
            'section' => 'products',
            'descendantOf' => $entryId,
        ],
        'transformer' => function(Entry $entry) {

            $products = [];
            // "orderItem" is entry field
            foreach ( $entry->orderItem as $product ) {
                $products = [
                    'title' => $product->titleVariation,
                ];
            }
            return $products;
        },
    ];
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the respond @HendrikEng. It will always overwrite the key so last item in array will return. It means that if entry field has more entries only last one will be returned.

Comment: do you want to get all title Variation fields of each entry in the section products?

Comment: updated the answer, it will now get all entries in products and loop over all orderItems and the titleVariation fields

Comment: First I access descendants of `entryId`. Than in descendant entry I access entry field `orderItem`. Than I must loop for in fields that I want to access. Field `titleVariation` is just an example so the code is not complicated.

Comment: Well, it still returns last entry from entry field `orderItem`. It seems like `$products[] = [ ... ];` is necessary to insert `$product` to array.

Comment: now i finally got what you mean , yes you will need it since the data array holds each entry which then holds an array of the titleVariation objects.

Comment: So it seems it's the only way to do it. So it means more work in JavaScript :( Thank you for the help @HendrikEng